# Using Pi as the man in the middle between internal and external resources

Tags: raspberry-pi, intranet

I got a job recently where I have to make sure that the company's internet is able to connect to the media streaming system installed inside the server room. However due to some limitations, just by connecting it to the router is not a solution. Therefore, I've setup a Raspberry Pi which will allows me to connect the server room's intranet to the company's internet. Currently, I can use both resources on that Pi due to the interface wlan0 and eth0.

I was wondering if possible that I could access the media streaming system's GUI through the PI inside the company's internet.